# On what type of area, land or territory can you abandon your vehicle in California without providing a right to anyone to get your vehicle towed?

Tags: california, vehicle, motor-vehicle, parking, towing

...Other than land, area or territory of your own or under your control or one you have contractual permission for.

For 4 weeks? And for 3 months? More?

Comment: Abandoning personal property normally means one relinquishes all rights over it.

Comment: @RockApe In California, you don’t really relinquish your rights to the vehicle just become liable for all towing and storage fees to and maybe other fees to exert your rights to your vehicle.

Comment: @kisspuska and if you don't pay the towing company after it's been towed, they can get a lien against it and then sell it at auction to recover their costs.  If I'm reading this correctly they can get a Lien if you don't retrieve your car in 3 business days, and start the sale process 15 days later for <$4k cars and charge up to 60 days worth of storage fees.  For cars above $4k they can charge up to 120 days of fees, but I'm not seeing anything about a minimum period before starting the sale process. https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billNavClient.xhtml?bill_id=200920100AB519

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Sounds about right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None.

Putting something on a piece of land long term and prohibiting anyone to move it is effectively *occupying* that piece of land.

You only can occupy land that you either have legal rights to, or that encounters no objection from those who has (adverse possession). In the latter case, it's not that you don't "provide them right to tow", rather they just don't mind not towing it.

What you describe more resembles **homesteading**, but that is [not possible in California](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/28239/2682).

Comment: My country has 'on-street parking' where you can park on the side of public streets, unless signposted otherwise. As long as your car is taxed it can stay there indefinitely. Is this not the case in Californa?

Comment: @mjt When someone "abandons" a vehicle, it usually means they stop paying the registration fees, excise taxes, etc. This is the difference between long-term parking and abandoning.

Comment: I believe in California a vehicle parked on a public street for more than 72 hours can be towed.  It usually takes rather longer and a notice is put on the windshield warning of the impending tow.

Comment: Cal. Veh. Code § 22661.  “Any ordinance establishing procedures for the removal of abandoned vehicles shall contain all of the following provisions: (b) Making the ordinance inapplicable to (1) a vehicle or part thereof that is completely enclosed within a building in a lawful manner where it is not visible from the street or other public or private property or (2) a vehicle or part thereof that is stored or parked in a lawful manner on private property in connection with the business of a licensed dismantler, licensed vehicle dealer, or a junkyard. [...]

Comment: “[...] This exception shall not, however, authorize the maintenance of a public or private nuisance as defined under provisions of law other than this chapter.”

Comment: @Greendrake leaving your car on the street for a few weeks and less than 6 months in front of your home or elsewhere where  there are no signs prohibiting or limiting parking looks like parking, and doesn’t look like “homesteading” — that needs substantially continuous personal presence on land.

Comment: @kisspuska "leaving" differs. Your question is about _abandoning_ (which implies not paying car registration etc. in which case it can't be parked), not parking.

Comment: @mjt: Note that, e.g. in Germany, no-parking zones can be established with two weeks notice (often done when a person applies for a temporary no-parking zone in front of their residence for a moving truck or some sort of construction), so "stay indefinitely" relies on it staying legal to park there indefinitely. Otherwise, it might get towed.